# Lorentz boosts: pseudorapidity and transverse momentum

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics

Given a collider situation, where a particle can be described by its *pseudorapidity* $\eta$, *azimuthal angle* $\phi$ and *transverse momentum* $p_T$, one can produce intensity maps $(\eta,\phi,p_T)$.

The objective is to center the map on a particular object (subscript zero). One can easily rotate all objects in $\phi$, $\phi_i'=\phi_i-\phi_0\in [-\pi,\pi]$, such that $\phi_0'=0$. This is the "centering" in $\phi$.

However, I'd expect that "centering" in $\eta$ leads to complications, as it is not Lorentz-invariant. Making a similar transformation $\eta_i'=\eta_i-\eta_0$, how are the $p_{T,i}$ affected?